# Reaching a internal server behind monowall

Tags: linux, firewall

We're using M0n0wall as firewall/NAT, now we have the following situation:

Server A:

```
192.168.1.100
running Apache on :80, external IP: 1.2.3.4:10080
2 vhosts based on subdomain
app-test-01.domain.com
app-test-02.domain.com
```

Server B

```
192.168.1.101
running Apache on :80, external IP: 1.2.3.4:11080
2 vhosts based on subdomain
app-prod-01.domain.com
app-prod-02.domain.com
```

Now, when I want to have **Server B** connect to *app-test-01.domain.com:10080* but I get a connection refused. Is there anything I can do to allow it anyway, without using their internal IP-addresses ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't ever used M0n0wall, but I think that the M0n0wall Handbook could be helpful:

http://doc.m0n0.ch/handbook/

### Hope this helps,

SnoopyBBT